# Electron with Python Backend: How to pass data repeatedly from JS to Python

Tags: javascript, python, electron, parent-child

This is my first project with Electron, so still quite new to all of it. I am trying to build a desktop app using Python for the back end. The problem that I am having relates to passing data between the Javascript and Python.

Basically the idea is that when a user clicks a button, the Python script is started and a value is passed over from Javascript. When the user clicks another button, a new text value is passed over.

The Javascript parent process

```
const {PythonShell} =  require('python-shell');

function testSpawn(evt){
    if (evt.srcElement.id == "btnSpawnProcess"){
        childShellProcess.stdin.write('Some Text')
        childShellProcess.stdin.end()

        shellProcess.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log(message)
        });
    } else if (evt.srcElement.id == "btnEditProcess"){
        childShellProcess.stdin.write('Some Other Text')
        childShellProcess.stdin.end()
    }
}

var options = {mode: 'json'};
var shellProcess = new PythonShell('./model/testSpawn.py', options);
childShellProcess = shellProcess.childProcess;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("btnSpawnProcess").addEventListener("click", testSpawn);
    document.getElementById("btnEditProcess").addEventListener("click", testSpawn);
});
```

Python child process

```
import sys
import json
import csv
import time

message = sys.stdin.readline()

# Print 100x the message that is being passed
for i in range(100):
    print(json.dumps(message, ensure_ascii=False))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)  # Delay 1 sec
```

The desired console output should be

```
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Some Other Text     # After triggering the btnEditProcess button
...
```

Instead I am getting

```
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Uncaught Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end   # After triggering the btnEditProcess button
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
Some Text     # 1 s timeout
...
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work. I guess that my approach using `stdin` does not work because the stream has ended. But if I don't end the stream, it doesn't even start. After searching around a long time I still cannot find a decent solution. Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: My first thought: childShellProcess.stdin.write('Some Text') is somehow async, therefore stdin has already been closed before any write could have happened.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your thoughts. I have clarified above slightly. I do get a console printout. It's just that after the first `stdin` I cannot pass any other additional data in. Is this related to what you refer to as async?